# How do I utilize the pygame._sdl2.controller module? Does it even exist?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sdl-2

I'm in the throes of producing a game, and with my keyboard controls going well, I decided to start expanding into controller support. Following the documentation, I thought I had initialized `pygame.controller` and created two controller objects, but the compiler rejects it, saying that the controller module doesn't exist. And checking the auto-completion for `pygame.`, that is absolutely the case; I see the `pygame.joystick` module, I see a whole bunch of controller events (i.e. `CONTROLLER_BUTTON_A` and `CONTROLLERAXISMOTION`, all things listed in `pygame._sdl2.controller`'s documentation), but I see no controller object itself.

I originally started with `pygame.controller`, but on closer examination, I changed it to `pygame._sdl2.controller`, as per the documentation. No success; compiler still throws an error, saying `_sdl2` is not an attribute of pygame. I've searched to see if any other developers have been having similar problems, but it almost feels like I'm the first person to ever try to use the module - everyone else seems to use `pygame.joystick`, with no mention of `pygame._sdl2.controller`. And I would absolutely do the same; it just seems really convenient to scan for all controller button presses (and releases!) and comparing them to events like `CONTROLLER_BUTTON_A`.

So am I just missing something here? Do I need to update SDL2 or something? (Is that even a thing?) Is there a different way to fetch all button presses so I can compare them to the `CONTROLLER_BUTTON` events? (EDIT 2: I know that `pygame.joystick` has similar methods, they just aren't ABXY specific like `pygame._sdl2.controller` methods are documented to be.) I'm using what I believe to be the latest version of pygame (2.5.0). Thanks in advance for any help.

EDIT: Okay, on closer inspection of the `pygame.joystick` module, it seems very powerful, and it has mappings for modern controllers, which is useful. Though I'm probably gonna start moving in that direction, I'm still curious about this `pygame._sdl2.controller` thing; is it just deprecated, or what?

EDIT 2: Cool, my question got downvoted and closed as a duplicate for some reason, even though the "duplicate" provided does not answer my question in any way. The provided answer has nothing to do with the `pygame._sdl2.controller` module, only details `pygame.joystick`, and does not satisfy the questions of "how do I use the `pygame._sdl2.controller` module," and "does the Controller module even exist". I very much understand that `pygame.joystick` seems like a better solution, but it still doesn't answer why there's a **`pygame._sdl2.controller`** module that doesn't seem to work at all. Considering it's in the documentation  - "controller", under "other", at the top - it'd be nice to know ***why it's in the docs***, even though it's apparently not even available as a class of pygame.

Comment: Yeah, the tutorial side of `_sdl2.controller` is pretty much non-existent to my knowledge/ If you want to use anything from `_sdl2`, you need to explicitly import it: `import pygame._sdl2`, I usually like to do it like so `import pygame._sdl2 as pg_sdl2` and then I'd use it as `pg_sdl2.controller...` Not sure either why this was closed because your question is obviously about `_sdl2.controller`, though I have to say again that there's not that many that could tell you much about it. Likely best to join the pygame discord server if you want to discuss this module.

Comment: This is very helpful, and would be my selected answer! I had no idea that there was a full-on `pygame._sdl2` module that would need importing if I were to utilize it.  I mean, judging by the lack of support on this `_sdl2.controller` module, my time would be better-utilized pursuing the `pg.joystick` option, but I still knew I was missing a key detail that wasn't being pointed out by the docs. I also didn't realize there was pygame Discord, so I'll be checking that out momentarily. : ) Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question had been answered in the comments 16 days ago. **Mattiis**'s response was:

> Yeah, the tutorial side of `_sdl2.controller` is pretty much non-existent to my knowledge/ If you want to use anything from `_sdl2`, you need to explicitly import it: `import pygame._sdl2`, I usually like to do it like so `import pygame._sdl2 as pg_sdl2` and then I'd use it as `pg_sdl2.controller`... Not sure either why this was closed because your question is obviously about `_sdl2.controller`, though I have to say again that there's not that many that could tell you much about it. Likely best to join the pygame discord server if you want to discuss this module.

This was the exact answer to my question; I was unaware that there was a `pygame._sdl2` module that needed to be imported before I could access anything from SDL2. However, the key takeaway here is that `pygame.joystick` module is very powerful, it is more closely supported by the community than `pygame._sdl2.controller`, and the `joystick` documentation has button mappings for various popular controller types.